# System.TypeLoadException in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 Application

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-4.6

I'm trying to play with ASP.Net 5 MVC 6 application in Visual Studio 2015(Community) and dotnet framework 4.6.

I selected "Empty" from ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates.

But whenever I add MVC nuget package and build the project, it gives the following error-

> **Could not load type 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.IConfigurationSource' from assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.** 
>   at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.RuntimeHttpApplication.ApplicationStart(IHttpApplication application)
>   at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.HttpApplicationBase.InvokeApplicationStart(IHttpApplication application)

Here is my project.json-

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8"
},

"commands": {
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
},

 "frameworks": {
 "dnx451": { },
 "dnxcore50": { }
},

"publishExclude": [
"node_modules",
"bower_components",
"**.xproj",
"**.user",
"**.vspscc"
],
"exclude": [
"wwwroot",
"node_modules",
"bower_components"
]
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you share your `project.json`?

Comment: @armen.shimoon see the update.

Comment: Yep, looks like Thom got the right answer below: the versions are mismatched, you were pulling the version of MVC for beta8 while the rest of your project was for beta5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you missing some steps in the setup.

If you installed the latest tools for vs2015. you will have beta 8 templates.
If you done the setup right the templates will run. 
Watch for warnings in your project reference. Your project will not run when you have these warnings.
Fix these by setting the correct dnx version and / or nuget feed

Take a look at these documents 
[beta 8](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/releases)
[Installing on windows](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html)

Comment: Now it works like a charm. Many many thanks. I was stucked for last 3 days. Thanks again. +1.

Comment: @s.k.paul, what did you exactly do to fix it? I'm running into the same problem, but can't find a solution. When creating a new MVC 6 project with the "full" template, it compiles and runs fine, but I can't spot the difference between those two projects.